# Laravel Mongodb Or where in not working as it should be

Tags: mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

My Query is:

```
Collection::WhereIn('email',$email)->orWhereIn('mobile',$mobile)->get();
```

The Mongo query which is getting executed is:

```
db.collection.find({"$and":[{"deleted_at":null},{"email":{"$in":["dfsdf@fsd.dfgf","sa$d.c"]}}],"$or":[{"mobile":{"$in":["39834787348","349430984390"]}}]},[])
```

which is not getting the proper results

Actually the below Mongo query gives proper results, but how to execute that in Laravel.

```
db.collection.find({$or:[{"email":{$in:["dfsdf@fsd.dfgf","sa$d.c"]}},{"mobile":{$in:["9892230504"]}}]}).pretty()
```

I am using Laravels jeneggers/mongodb package.